# Does iOS built-in security framework support ECC and ECDH?

Tags: ios, security, public-key-encryption, shared-secret

I could find an answer from 2013 that iOS does not support ECC based encryption and a recommendation to use OpenSSL. I see at the [Security Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityFrameworkReference/_index.html) some definitions for TLS_ECDH but it is not clear to me that ECC based is fully supported. I need to be able to generate a key pair based on secp256r1 and use the other party 64 byte public key to generate a shared secret by using ECDH. I also need to be able to use ECDSA to sign and verify signatures.

Comment: You are going to need a `Common Crypto` expert to answer this as it sounds like some specific domain knowledge is required rather than general programming support. It might be quicker to ask the question on the Apple Developer forums.